# Issues Unlocking the Dream Suit

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I am having trouble unlocking the dream suit, I have been mayor for 9 days now, have built a public works project on my second day so it's been at least 7 days since I built the project, I have played on WiFi too, and whenever I go into the town hall Isabelle is always awake.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a certain time I have to find her sleeping? Did I forget something?

Comment: It's semi-randomized, so it may take more time. Many people in the threads I've looked at said it took them ten days.

Comment: @pushasha, do you have a link to these sources?

Comment: @Daniel [Link](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/answers/353428-how-do-you-unlock-dream-suite-its-been-9-days-and-isabell-has-not-gone-to-sleep), [link](http://www.belltreeforums.com/showthread.php?74925-How-to-unlocked-dream-suite), [link](http://www.animalcrossingcommunity.com/Topic/6254623/1/Question_Re_Unlocking_Dream_Suite), [link](http://www.belltreeforums.com/showthread.php?70623-Seems-like-I-can-t-unlock-anything-Help)

Comment: @pushasha Thank you! Maybe provide your comment as an answer with the sources added to it, so other people with this question have an easy reference?

Comment: @Daniel I didn't feel comfortable posting it as an answer, since none of those forum threads seemed like hard evidence. If no one else comes up with anything, I'll consider posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Skip a couple of days and see what happens. If there is still nothing, spend an hour or two on the internet on the DS so it can clock that you've connected.